# 18.04 apt-get libglfw-dev no installation candidate

Tags: 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. When I try `sudo apt-get install libglfw-dev` then I get this error: `E: Package 'libglfw-dev' has no installation candidate`. Was this package removed in 18.04?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/libglfw3-dev) solve your problem?

Comment: @Joe Bedard, please always use `apt-cache search [name]` (or part of name) to decide the actual package name. Or use the on-line search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglfw&searchon=names

Comment: @Knud: If I had posted this, it'd be worth and answer!